# How to change database config magento 2.2.x?

Tags: magento2.2

I have created new database and want change current store to new database, where i can change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple, you can change config database on the file app/etc/env.php

See my screen :

[image]

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any question